# Eck local persistent volume not created

Tags: elasticsearch

Trying to create a local persistent volume for ECK
Creating persistent volumes with the following definition

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-data-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mo/esdata"
```

And PVC

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-data
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Getting Error on PVC

```
kubectl apply -f pvc-es.yml 
Warning: kubectl apply should be used on resource created by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply
The PersistentVolumeClaim "elasticsearch-data-quickstart-es-default-0" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: is immutable after creation except resources.requests for bound claims
```

Answer (score 0):

First, have you created the storage class "manual"?

Second, it seems that in the error message is saying the pvc is immutable after creation. Is it possible you have created a pvc with the same name before? Please run `kubectl get pvc` and show output. you can delete the pvc and reapply the yaml if it is the case.